# How can I make my hacked WPDN run faster?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, performance, pandigital-novel

I have a [white Pandigital Novel](http://www.pandigital.net/pandigitalnovel) that I [hacked to run Android 2.1.](http://www.slatedroid.com/index.php?topic=5098.0)  Is there any way I can make it and the apps it runs go faster?  It's already overclocked to 800Mhz and I have no home screen shortcuts.  Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: the question is not "is it fast?", but "is it fast enough?"; is there any specific goal why you want to make it faster? Are you feeling the device is laggy, or are you just aiming for faster benchmark?

Comment: @Lie: Certain apps and sometimes the device itself are somewhat/very laggy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using JIT (Just In Time) compiler (e.g. installing Froyo, Gingerbread, or "Frozen Eclair") will typically increase CPU-bound processes by 3-5 times.

If your device use FAT, RFS, or NTFS filesystem, your device might be faster by converting to ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem. However, if you want to prolong the lifetime of your internal memory, use YAFFS2 filesystem.

Comment: I am not familiar with JIT. -Googles- Looks good.  Can you elaborate on how I apply it here?

Comment: @John: upgrade to Froyo/Gingerbread, which comes with JIT. Alternatively, it is possible to backport Froyo's JIT to Eclair or possibly earlier, I've used the "Frozen Eclair" mod which gives a similar performance improvement to Froyo's JIT (on benchmarks).

Answer (score 0):

in order to use JIT and installing froyo, search cm6 wpdn. its a cyanogenmod 6 hack where you can make all sorts of tweaks, including the ones the other guy gave you

Comment: Instead of instructing the OP to do a search, can you not do a search, find the information, and summarize it here (with a link, if needed)?